# Css fixed height content inner beetwen footer and header

Tags: css

First look at the picture:
[image]

Like you see my center of page i mean this content with form on small resolution get over the navbar. This content is centered verticaly and horizontal by flex.

here is code and what i try:
html`

```
<nav>
  <div class='row header-inner'>
    <div class='col-md-10 col-lg-10 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-11 col-xs-12'>

      <div class='row logo-inner'>
        <img src="assets\static\Logo.png">
      </div>
      <div class='row menu-inner'>
        <a class='menu-item' routerLink="/aboutUs" routerLinkActive="active">about us</a>
        <a class='menu-item' routerLink="/skiCams" routerLinkActive="active">skicams</a>
        <a class='menu-item' routerLink="/contactUs" routerLinkActive="active">contact</a>
      </div>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>

<div class='row content-inner'>
  <div class='col-md-8 col-lg-8  col-lg-offset-2 col-md-offset-2 col-sm-offset-1 col-sm-10 col-xs-12'>
    <router-outlet></router-outlet>
  </div>
</div>



<footer>
  <div class='row center-block'>
    <div class='col-md-offset-5 col-lg-offset-5 col-md-2 col-lg-2 col-sm-offset-5 col-sm-2 col-xs-offset-3 col-xs-6 footer-content'>
      Powered by PGS
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>`
```

and css

```
 footer {
    border-top: 1px solid #40637e;
    background-color: #282828;
    position: fixed;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    height: 110px;
    width: 100%;
    overflow:hidden;
}

.footer-content{
    color :#959595;
    border-top :1px solid #959595;
    text-align: center;
    margin-top:30px;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 10px;
}

.logo-inner{
    margin: 35px 0px 35px 0px;
}

.header-inner{
    border-bottom:1px solid #dbdbdb;
    padding-bottom: 13px;
    margin: 0;
}

.menu-inner{
    margin:0px;
}

.menu-item{
    margin-right: 40px;
    padding-bottom: 15px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    font-weight: bold;
    color:#545454;

}

.active{
    border-bottom:1px solid #ef6716;
    color: #ef6716;
}

a:hover, a:focus {
    color: #ef6716;
    text-decoration: none;
}

.content-inner{
    background-color:#f8f8f8;
    margin: 0;
    /*margin-bottom:200px;*/
}

@media(max-width : 768px){
    .menu-item{
    margin-right:30px;
    padding-bottom: 14px;
    font-size: 14px;
    text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu-inner{
    margin:0px;
    text-align: center;
}
.logo-inner{
    margin: 35px 0px 35px 0px;
    text-align: center;
}
}
```

could you help my do something like this when the height is smaller the page start scrolling ?

Comment: Try setting `min-height` to `content-inner` with `overflow: auto;`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you're missing your flexbox code in your question. Without seeing it all, I'd suggest trying to remove flexbox in the smaller breakpoints and just using `display: block;` and making sure your `<div class='row content-inner'>` element is statically positioned (`position: static;`).